# C++ - AllocConsole crash + Printing to the console

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, dll-injection

Ok, I have a couple questions about using AllocConsole that I couldn't find many answers too and some of the solutions I found are not compatible with my code or something because they are just not doing what I want them to do.

So before I start here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h" // don't forget to include "Windows.h" inside stdafx.h
#include <iostream>

DWORD LocalPlayer_Offset = 0xA30504;
DWORD FlashDuration_Offset = 0xA2F8;
DWORD Jump_Offset = 0x4EE0D38;
DWORD Flag_Offset = 0x100;
DWORD BaseAddress = 0;
DWORD* Jump = nullptr;
DWORD* LocalPlayer = nullptr;

int flashActive = 1;
int bhopActive = 1;

using namespace std;

void Init()
{
    BaseAddress = reinterpret_cast< DWORD >(GetModuleHandle("client"));
    Jump = reinterpret_cast< DWORD* >(BaseAddress + Jump_Offset);
    LocalPlayer = reinterpret_cast< DWORD* >(BaseAddress + LocalPlayer_Offset);

    //These don't print to the console?
    AllocConsole();
    printf("injected");
    cout << "injected";
}
void InitStub() { return; }

DWORD WINAPI functions(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (*LocalPlayer) // check for nullptr
        {
            if (bhopActive) {
                if (*reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(*LocalPlayer + Flag_Offset) & 1 &&
                    GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & (1 << 15)) 
                    *Jump = 6; 
            }
            if (flashActive) {
                if (*reinterpret_cast<float*>(*LocalPlayer +     FlashDuration_Offset) > 0.f)
                    *reinterpret_cast<float*>(*LocalPlayer + FlashDuration_Offset) = 0.f;
            }
        }
    }
}
void functionsStub() { return; }

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID     lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        Init();
        CreateThread(nullptr, 0, functions, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        return TRUE;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        return TRUE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

This all works fine so don't flame me because of the code, I am quite new to internals and am trying to learn.

My issues are that in the Init() function, the printf and cout do not print anything to the AllocConsole() function. It does open a console successfully and the process uses that console so I know it works fine. Why do they not print to the console, and can I use this console from other functions within my program.

Also, this AllocConsole when closed by itself crashes the application, is this because it is not free? I am not sure how to successfully use FreeConsole because AllocConsole is not working the way I want it too.

Comment: The CRT has already initialized the stdout/stderr/cout/cerr streams but without knowing anything about the console you created.  You have to re-initialize the streams with freopen().  Closing the console with the close button *always* terminates the process.  Creating a console is just an all-around lousy idea, use the debugger.

Comment: How do I use the debugger?

Comment: Is it legal to CreateThread in DllMain()?

Comment: That is not the important part. I am not sure how to use freopen to make it work?

Comment: @V.Kravchenko: yes.  It's discouraged, but that's only because you'll deadlock if you then try to *wait* on the new thread to do something.  So long as you realize that the new thread doesn't actually start until DllMain() has exited, you'll be fine.

Comment: Best to avoid using the CRT in injected code.  Try using WriteConsoleOutput or WriteFile instead.  Also, it would be safer to call AllocConsole and do the I/O in the new thread rather than DllMain.  Or, as Hans says, don't create a console at all, use OutputDebugString or write to a file.  In test code, calling MessageBox is safe enough too if you do it from a separate thread.

Comment: Well you have to see what my issues are here. I am trying my best to not be detected by an anticheat software so calling a MessageBox is a really stupid idea overall.

Comment: It looked to me like the output was only there so you could tell that the injection was succeeding, so I assumed that as soon you'd got the injection code working, you'd get rid of it.  If your production code will need to produce output, that would probably be best sent to a file, or perhaps a pipe back to your injecting process.  (A console *might* work, given the changes I suggested, it just sounds risky.  The presence of a console is also the sort of thing that would be trivial for anticheat software to detect.)